# .netCore 5 Area route Not working in RedirectToActionArea and go as a query string

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, area

when I use below command In `asp.net core 5`

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SystemUsersManagement", new { area = "admin" });
```

it not Works properly and get `Status Code: 404; Not Found Error`. and Area go as a query string like

```
https://localhost:44322/SystemUsersManagement/Index?area=admin
```

where is wrong.

my controller :

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class SystemUsersManagementController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
       //do something
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "SystemUsersManagement", new { area = "admin" });
    }
}
```

My route in startup:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
          );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
                );
                routes.MapRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
                routes.MapRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" });
                routes.MapRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" });
            });
```

also in ConfigureService
.
.

```
services.AddMvc(option=>option.EnableEndpointRouting=false).AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });
```

Comment: Hi @Morteza Jangjoo, any update? Did my answer resolve your issue? If not, please follow up. If so, remember to accept as answer.

Comment: Hi @Rena. Unfortunately my problem was not solved

Comment: Hi @Morteza Jangjoo, It works well in my project, so it seems your project still contains any other problems you may not share. I suggest you could create a new project and follow my project structure to test. If you could share a simple repo will be more helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure add `[Area]` attribute in your controller like below:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class SystemUsersManagementController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The Project structure should be like below:

[image]